# Can I remap <C-(key)> while replacing a character? If not, is there a workaround or hack?

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode, replace

I have i-mapped `<C-a>`, `<C-s>` etc. to commonly used keys that I use often but find annoying to type normally, for example `*` and `_`. It works as expected in insert mode, but when executing a single-character replacement with `r`, I get some kind of escape sequence instead.

I've tried `nnoremap r<C-(key)> character` and `nmap r<C-(key)> character`, but seemingly-random things happen when i execute `r<C-(key)>`. Mapping to different characters (symbols) gives very different results. Prefixing the character with `\` just makes nothing happen.

What is a way I can remap `<C-(key)>` while replacing a character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be done through the feature known as "language mapping". This feature allows entry of non-English/ASCII characters using a standard keyboard but more generally allows one to control the mapping of *characters entered into a buffer* which is what `r` emits.

You need to do two things:

1. Use `lmap` for the mapping rather than `imap`. E.g. `:lnoremap <c-a> *`
2. Enable language mapping. This can be done with `:set iminsert=1` or by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> (control-caret) while in insert mode.

Besides `:h :lmap` see `:h 45.5`, `:h i_Ctrl-^` and `:h 'iminsert'`

Note that `lmap` also applies to characters entered while in Insert mode so `lmap` should be all you need for your general use case of replacing "annoying" characters with easier-to-type variants.